# change returnURL with window.location using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following link:

```
<ul id="countrySelect">
<ul>
<li><a href="setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&amp;localesetting=en-US">EN</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li><a href="setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&amp;localesetting=cs-CZ">CZ</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- END COUNTRY SELECT LIST -->
<p></p>
</ul>
```

I would like to remove the `Default.aspx` from the returnURL and replace it with the current page the user is on. This is what i have tried, but not sure if its correct?

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var countryArr = [];
var $ul = $('<ul id="countrySelect"/>');

countryArr = $('ul#countrySelect ul li a').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

$.each(countryArr, function() {

$ul.append('<li>' + '<a href="setlocale.aspx?returnURL=' + pathname + '&localesetting=' + this.slice(0) + '">' + this.slice(3) + '</a>');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not do this, basically iterate through each `<a>` and do a `string.replace` on the `href` attribute:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var oldHref = $(this).attr("href");

    var newHref = oldHref.replace("Default.aspx", window.location.pathname);

    $(this).attr("href", newHref);
});​​​
```

This obviously wouldn't work if you're replacing more than `Default.aspx` though. You'd need the following:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var oldHref = $(this).attr("href");

    // get the URL to string.replace
    var toReplace = oldHref.substring(oldHref.indexOf("=") + 1, oldHref.indexOf("&"));

    var newHref = oldHref.replace(toReplace, window.location.pathname);

    $(this).attr("href", newHref);
});​​​
```

Comment: I guess that would be more simple!

Comment: its not changing the returnURL even though i added this line: `$("ul#countrySelect ul li a").each(function() {`

Comment: @Super2 interesting, it's working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Pjhpq/ - are you getting any errors? Try debug mode IE = F12, Chrome = CTRL+SHIFT+J and view the script window.